# What do these two places have in common?

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge, real

In the United States of America, the New York City Borough of **Queens** lies at the west end of Long Island.

More than 5000km across the Atlantic ocean lies the Metropolitan Borough of **Bolton**, a borough of Greater Manchester, England.

Two seemingly unrelated places, and yet they both have an uncanny connection. Think beyond the obvious - you may need to do some research to figure out what I am driving at.

Comment: While it may or may not affect the puzzle, this is geographically incorrect - the borough of Queens lies at the _west_ end of Long Island.

Comment: Thank you @JeffZeitlin, it doesn't affect the puzzle, but you are quite right. I originally drafted that it was the easternmost borough of NYC, it was an error.

Comment: Bolton has a [Queen's Park](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Queens+Park/@53.5788183,-2.4354963,15.15z) but the reverse is not true. There is a Bolton Avenue across the East River in the Bronx.

Comment: I feel like "uncanny" or "driving at" might be clues, but haven't figured anything out yet.

Comment: The Metropolitan Borough of Bolton is a borough of **Greater Manchester**, not Manchester (which is a city, and a borough in its own right).

Comment: If it requires research, then perhaps the [Knowledge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge) tag would be applicable

Comment: @gnovice very perceptive! There may even be a little more to it than that.

Comment: They are both 6 letters long. Both have 4 distinct letters and one repeating letter (**o** for Bolton and **e** for Queens).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Here are some additional clues and the answer I intended.

There were in fact **two** clues hidden in the original question:

**CLUE #1**

> I used the expression **'driving at'** to hint that the answer was related in some way to driving.

**CLUE #2**

> I said that the two places *had* an **'uncanny connection'**. Note that I didn't say they *shared* this connection, although it is something they have in common. 'Uncanny' can imply supernatural. A 'connection' is a link between two things, for example two places.

**ADDITIONAL CLUE**

> If you consider the two clues above together hopefully you will have realised the answer I was looking for is to do with a **road** (driving, connection) and that there is something unusual, eerie, possibly supernatural involved.

**ANSWER**

> The answer I was looking for was that they both have roads named for something associated with The Devil. Bolton is served by a road numbered the A666 ('666' is The Devil's number), while Queens is served by Interstate 495, more commonly known as the Long Island Expressway, or 'LIE'... and The Devil is also called the father of the LIE.

Comment: "Uncanny can imply supernatural". Not any more than anything else strange. And the explanation for how Queens' part of it works makes no sense.

Comment: You comment includes a quote that I blanked out as a spoiler.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think it important enough to blank out, because IMO this answer is so tenuous that the connection wouldn't be gettable even *with* that hint. (If it weren't posted by you, the original poser of the question, I would not have thought it was the intended answer at all.)

Comment: @Deusovi Well you didn't attempt an answer, so I can't possibly imagine what you think the correct answer ought to be. Nevertheless, that is the answer to my puzzle. I believe it could be solved using Google. A search of 'Uncanny' shows all of its synonyms, including the one I intended. A google search of the two places shows them on a map including the roads, at least one of which is plainly obvious and I thought would lead to looking for the connection to the other.

Comment: If I *knew* what the correct answer ought to be, I would have posted it. But the issue is that the "666 -> devil -> father of lies (according to one Bible verse) -> lie -> L.I.E. -> Long Island Expressway" connection is so indirect that it's hardly a connection at all. Yes, both of those roads exist, but so do *many other roads*. The connection in Niranj's answer is much more clear than this one.

Comment: @Deusovi That is one translation of the bible. The first one that comes up in Google, interestingly (so you DO know how to Google). The well known King James translation only uses 'lie' in singular form. Regarding Niranj's answer - he at least got the driving connection which I commended him for. You did not attempt an answer at all. I'm not sure what you are driving at now - do you think I should make Niranj's answer the correct one even though it isn't the one I intended? There really isn't anything 'uncanny' about his answer. There is a 'Blackburn Road' in Bolton too, that is another place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71257/discussion-between-astralbee-and-deusovi).

Answer (score 7):

I got some common things from your `driving` word hint.

> There is **[Bolton Road](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Bolton+Rd,+Far+Rockaway,+NY+11691,+USA/@40.6077255,-73.7476297,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c265fdcfc1e7ff:0xd9dea2cdec61a8d1!8m2!3d40.6077255!4d-73.745441?hl=en)** in `Queens` and **[Queens Road](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Queens+Rd,+Bolton+BL3+4ER,+UK/@53.5641923,-2.4581042,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x487ba7be1e6a2ef9:0xb9b5a061c6284cfa!8m2!3d53.5641923!4d-2.4559155?hl=en)** in `Bolton`

Comment: You were the closest to my intended answer, which I have now posted.

Answer (score 2):

Is it that:

> both of those places have something to do with cocktails?

Because...

> Long Island and Metropolitan are both names of cocktails.

Comment: A very good answer! But it isn't the one I was thinking of. There are two clues within the question.